# Delete text after "more" tag (PHP)

Tags: php

How to delete text after !--more-- tag?

I tried:

```
function addMore($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/!--more--(.*)/', ' ', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just get the substring from the beginning till the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the 's' modifier to make the preg work even on break lines:

```
function addMore($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/!--more--(.*)/s', ' ', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

look here:
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the string, replacing it with the !--more--:

```
$text = preg_replace('/!--more--.*/', '!--more--', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "plain to you howhings of the great explorer of the truth.!--more-- plain to you how allt the truth,/";
echo $short = substr($text, 0, strpos( $text, '!--more--'));
```

Output:
http://codepad.org/atXzthBc

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use **explode** function or simply **substr** as below :

```
$text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, '!-more-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addMore($text) {
$newtext=explode("!--more--",$text);

return $newtext[0];
}
```